# Updating to Material-UI v1.x.x

Tags: javascript, css, version-control, migration, material-ui

My app currently uses Material-/ui v0.17.0 and in order for it to work with React v16.0.0 I have to upgrade to Material-UI v1.0.0.

I have seen the migration tool [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-codemod). This just updates the import statements more or less. A lot of the props appear to have changed and are not backwards compatible. The tool actually would not work for me so 
I manually updated all of my imports. It is almost looking like I have to rewrite the entire front end code of this app using the new updated v1.0.0 components. There has got to be a better way to do this. I understand that major version changes are "breaking" changes but this version upgrade may as well be an entirely new package. I cannot be the only person who has had to upgrade to v1.0.0 and am curious to how others have been able to successfully migrate over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my specific project the solution seemed to be that I could use `react` v16.4.1 with `material-ui` v0.20.0. In doing so I had to drop `react-tap-event-plugin` which is not compatible with `react` versions >=16.4.0. This involved converting `onTapEvent` tags to `onClick`. Fortunately, by not having to upgrade the the new major version of material-ui, I did not have to update my components which was my fear.

All of this aside, I did spend some time converting `material-ui` components to v1.2.0 before I arrived at my solution which did not require these component modifications. When attempting to perform these changes, the documentation was sparse. I did find another Stack Overflow thread asking about the migration to v1.x.x [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640596/migration-steps-from-material-ui-v0-x-to-v1-y/50804373#50804373).

In that thread I linked to a couple of github issues that raised the same concern, and they are likely a valuable resource to keep your eye on if you yourself are trying to make this version transition.

[[docs] 0.x => 1.x migration guide #7195](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7195)

[Codemod error when upgrading from v0.18.7 to v1.1.0 #11819](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11819)

[As well as some code someone documented when making the transition.](https://gist.github.com/anuragagarwal561994/44447847bbcc3059c6d10e2be1e92ff1)

[Here is a project where someone went through upgrading to mui 1.x.x from 0.x.x](https://github.com/u-wave/web/pull/844/commits)

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed the API is not backward compatible and the [migration guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0.x) is to be continued... I think there is a reason for that.

Although most of the components have their replacement, it looks like there is no straightforward way to migrate, especially because some components like autocomplete are not present in 1.x. If you heavily invested in restyling the components with touching the internals, you'll have even harder time, since in 1.x JSS is proposed way of styling.

The only way I see now is to rewrite it component by component. That's not something you'd like to read in the migration guide:)

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this is somewhat preposterous? For example, migrating from using a <Dialog> component now requires I use: Dialog  DialogActions  DialogContent  DialogContentText  DialogTitle. I'd love to know how large websites/apps complete their migrations. I would doubt they would just rewrite everything component by component.

Comment: On the other hand we've bumped React to 16 with material-ui 0.x and didn't notice any visual regressions (~15k LOC project). We were also trying to use material-ui-next as they suggest to port our components one by one and it worked as well, so we were able to use 0.x and 1.x components within the same application. Anyway we abandoned that project due to other reasons and started over from scratch with latest material and react versions.

Comment: Are you saying that I could run my app with React v16.0.0 and not upgrade my material-ui to v1.0.0? I am using webpack as well if that influences your answer.

Comment: Yes it worked in our webpack-based setup. If I recall correctly, the only problem was with some 3rd party packages which had their peerDependency set to fixed React 15. material-ui itself accepts React 16, take a look at package.json https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v0.x/package.json

Comment: I can't seem to get React v16 to work with Material UI v0.17.0 even though the package.json in mui shows it should be compatible with react versions ^15.5.0 . I end up with the issue of having multiple versions of react installed (apparently).

Comment: Looks like compatibility with React v16 came in MUI v0.18.7 with commit: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/commit/8032d51c3faf4ddc5bcf814c9458fbc227a083e2#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2 Have you tried this one? Bumping MUI to v0.18.7 (or even latest 0.20.1) and getting rid of React v15.5.x seems safer and more reasonable to me than keeping 2 version of react.

Comment: Bumping up my version revealed errors with the react-tap-event-plugin. Still unclear how react v16+ can coexist with m-ui v0.x.x . Many packages depend on react v15.x.x. There must be a way to run react v16.x.x with m-ui v0.x.x otherwise m-ui must be updated to v1.0.0 which means manually updating many components

Comment: Running mui v0.18.7 with react v16.3.2 with react-tap-event-plugin v3.0.3 seems to work...until I try to work with the package in another project where it comes with a .jspm.errors files saying the syntax is all incorrect for every line in the code

Comment: Hard to say, but it is generally caused by incorrect babel/webpack setup when there are errors everywhere. I'd start with comparing webpack configs and babelrc in the projects.