# Migration steps from Material UI v0.x to v1.y

Tags: material-ui

I have been using material UI v0 from a while and Now I wanted to move to MUI v1.x as v0.x is deprecated.
Request to provide a migration guide.

Comment: https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/

Comment: @thirtydot while that is pretty much all that is currently available, I think you'd agree it is not very helpful and less than comprehensive

Comment: @BobSmith: It was helpful for me, but I agree that it's not very comprehensive. I migrated a project from v0 to v1, and it was a long and boring find/replace session with lots of "read the docs/demos/code to see what changed". Seeing [an example](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8kcgdi/materialui_v1_is_out/dz6t9rb/) of a completed migration helped a bit. Just go through your entire project and replace all `RaisedButton`s, then all `FlatButton`s, repeat for each component until done. And remember, you don't have to do it all in one go.

Comment: After looking into this issue for a few days now, this comment has been the most helpful so far. That example will be invaluable to others making this migration as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link that @thirtydot provided is really all that is available. Not too much documentation is available (yet) for this major version change migration.

Keep your eye on these issues:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7195

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11819

So far the best thing I have seen is: https://gist.github.com/anuragagarwal561994/44447847bbcc3059c6d10e2be1e92ff1